# Beginner control flow concerns in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, uilocalnotification

In a basic Reminder app, I have delegate method where I call a method `scheduleNotification` to schedule a UILocalNotification and call an additional method `addReminderToDataModel` to save the Reminder data to NSUserDefaults. Here is my code...

```
- (void)detailViewControllerDidSave:(DetailViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self scheduleNotification: controller.reminderData];
        [self addReminderToDataModel: controller.reminderData];
    }];
}
```

The two methods do not rely on each other at all, so it doesn't matter what order they fire. I  may be over thinking this, but is there any advantage to fire one of the methods only when the other has completed, with blocks or simply at the end of the first method's implementation? Part of the reason I'm asking this is because I need to assign a `reminderId` to `reminderData` before I call either of these methods.

Comment: Are scheduleNotification and addReminderToDataModel async methods then?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking if there is an advantage to making them async even when they don' rely on each other. In the way the are called above, even though one is called after the other, they are not async?

Comment: if they are both async, you should call one within the other inside the async block.